# Is it possible to select Terminal output by using keyboard keys?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Often I like to copy output from the terminal into the clipboard.

Currently I'm using the mouse. Select the text so that it is marked. Then "command" plus "c".

In a text-editor or text-processing software you can use the "shift" key (keep it pushed) together with the arrow keys for selecting text. So one needs the mouse less and can keep the hands on the keyboard.

On the terminal that doesn't work. Keeping the "shift" key pushed and pushing the arrow keys just creates this: *;2C;2B;2A;2D;2D;2D;2D;2D*

Hexadecimal numbers obviously. Does anyone knows the meaning?

But my actual question is:

**Can one select terminal output via keyboard?**

Similar to what I have described concerning text-editors.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to select a particular piece of output from Terminal, but shift+cmd+up will select all output of the previous command.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but you can copy the output of a command to the clipboard by doing `somecommand | pbcopy`.

Comment: Also, if you use something like `screen` or iTerm2, there are ways to select text using the keyboard (perhaps not faster than using the mouse though).

Comment: @leekaiinthesky : Thanks a lot. :) That's indeed very handy too know ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal multiplexing program *tmux* has configurable keyboard commands for selecting text for the purpose of copying and pasting.  *tmux* is a very powerful addition to any terminal.  It has a high learning curve, but if all you want to do is copy and paste you can learn how in a matter of moments and it will stay completely out of your way until you are ready to take the next step.  *tmux* can be installed directly, or using a package manager such as Macports or Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

> Can one select terminal output via keyboard?

There's limited keyboard use when interacting with the scrollback buffer.  It wasn't really designed to have "text editing" capabilities as that's what a text editor is for.  Per the [Terminal Users Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac), you only have the following "navigation" keys:

| Action | Keyboard Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Scroll to top | <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> |
| Scroll to bottom | <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> |
| Page up | <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> |
| Page down | <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> |
| Line up | <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> |
| Line down | <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> |
| Set Mark | <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> |
| Unset Mark | <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> |

As you can see, there's no lateral movement available - you can select whole lines, but not individual characters.  Terminal is, after all, a GUI app and it appears to be intended to have these "advanced" text selection done with a mouse.

### Redirect your output

- Redirect your output to a file:

  ```
  mycommand > output.txt         ← Captures all output to the file (overwrites file)
  mycommand >> output.txt        ← Captures all output and appends to the file (no overwrite)
  ```

- Pipe  your output to `pbcopy` (macOS clipboard)

  ```
  mycommand | pbcopy
  ```

#### Real World Example:

Using tools like `grep`, `cut` or `awk`, you can get just the data you're looking for.  For example, suppose we want to find our what the router IP address is.  We could issue the command `ipconfig getpacket en0`. From there you'll get all of the DHCP info that was assigned to your network interface `en0`.  You can then search through and find what you're looking for like the router’s IP.  There are easier ways to extract this info:

- Using `grep` we can narrow it down to a single line:

  ```
  ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep router
  router (ip_mult): {192.168.0.1}      ← Result
  ```
- If you're trying to capture certain things you can rerun your command and with a little creative use of the `cut` command, we can "extract" the IP

  ```
  ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep router | cut  -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
  192.168.0.1                          ← Result
  ```

- Finally, you can send it directly to your clipboard by redirecting/piping *that* output to your clipboard via `pbcopy`

  ```
  ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep router | cut  -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1 | pbcopy
                          ← Blank line result! It's in your clipboard!
  ```

Granted, this example is a bit extreme on the pipe (`|`) usage and you should be aware that every pipe creates a sub-process; in other words, it's very inefficient!  However, for small items such as this, this really isn't an issue.

### Using tmux

`tmux` is an excellent tool and I agree with everything said in [the answer that suggested it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249822/119271), however, there's some missing context that should be addressed:

*tmux's power comes from the ability to keep a session alive in the event of a disconnect; it should be installed on the *server* for best results.  Yes, you can run it locally, but it's like using a cannon to kill a mosquito*.

#### Use builtin `screen`

Again, I'm a huge fan of `tmux`, but instead of installing something to only use 10% or less of it's features, use `screen` that's included with macOS. It has the same features and [includes the navigation keys to mark and copy text](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Copy-and-Paste).  Here's a short sampling:

| Action | Key Binding |
| --- | --- |
| move the cursor left | <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> |
| move the cursor down | <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> |

The full (lengthy) list can be found at the above link.

Comment: I like this I’m gonna show my boss this one.  I tried it but the command is long and alot to remember .  Can you make a shortcut or something?

Comment: Glad I could help you out @DougMasters